# How to recognise if the .exe file needs input parameters

Tags: c++

How can someone recognise if he needs to put input parameters for an executable in C++.

What commands should you find in a code to know which parameters are needed?

For example if you need to run it like this: **hello.exe test.txt**.  But you dont know it.

So you run the hello executable but it needs a text file next to it. 
How can someone recognise in the code that this kind of parameters are needed??

**EDIT**: my source code has main like this
int main(int argc,char *argv[]) but what exactly can the arguments be?

The only place that the argc and argv appear is at this lines.

```
 #ifdef PARALLEL            
        Test.CVodeInit_parallel(states,startTime,argc,argv);
   #else
        Test.CVodeInit_serial(states,startTime);
  #endif
```

Comment: Are you disassembling the program in question?

The arguments passed to an application are passed to the main(...) function in the form of a char array.

Answer (score 1):

For example - if someone runs your code like this:

**hello.exe test.txt**

then argc will be 2, argv[0] = "hello.exe", argv[1] = "test.txt"

but if they run the code like this:

**hello.exe**

then argc will be 1, argv[0] = "hello.exe"

Is that the question you are asking about? Basically argc is an integer, and tells you how many strings are in the argv array

Answer (score 0):

parameters are passed to the program as parameters of the `main` function, which should look like this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
```

where `argc` is the number of parameters and `argv` is an array of strings containing the actual arguments.

So check in the code whether these parameters are handled.

NOTE: the `main` function can also look like this:

```
int main()
```

which is legal but mean that the program does not expect, or handles, parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You write "in the code" but you are asking about the ".exe". It is unclear whether you have access to the **source**-code or want to derive it from the raw binary.

In the former case you would have to take a look at the main()/WinMain()-function (or equivalent entry-point), the latter case would probably be impractical / too difficult as it involves disassembly and heuristics.

Comment: That is great, so try to find the main()/WinMain() or similar main-function, then take a look at which parameters they take, typically this is argc/argv. Then take a look at the place where they access those variables.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way to take a live executable and ask it what arguments it takes. Most EXEs that take arguments have a `-h` or `--help` or `/h` or something similar that displays what arguments it takes. But outside of that, no.

From source code, you can kind of reconstruct its arguments. Many program use some GNU tool to parse arguments from `argv`, so you'll need to be familiar with that to understand what it's doing. [Boost.ProgramOptions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/program_options.html) is an alternative that some people use. And others just parse the arguments manually, so you have to walk the code and watch what it pulls out of `argv`.

---

> The only place that the argc and argv appear is at this lines.

Then you must look at the implementation of `Test.CVodeInit_parallel` to know what arguments it takes.